Wrong architecture libraries transferred to Apple Silicon Mac
A few months ago I moved my world wholesale from an Intel Mac to an Apple Silicon Mac. Recently, I was trying to get a cmake project to build that involved several SDL2 related libraries installed by homebrew. Some of them reported, "wrong architecture." Then I discovered that I had two worlds going:
/opt/homebrew/lib with Apple silicon architecture libraries,
/usr/local/lib with Intel architecture libraries, brought over wholesale from my previous Mac.
I resolved my immediate problem by uninstalling everything related to SDL2 and reinstalling it. That came up clean. But /usr/local/lib is still very well populated, with some libraries of the wrong architecture and some that have dual architectures. Is this a ticking time bomb that needs to be defused? What is the right algorithm for cleanly dealing with this?

Had similar issue recently, didn't know Migration Assistant from Intel to Apple Silicon would copy over all x86 based packages which might cause compile issues later. So I am sharing my answer wider to just homebrew.
2 options I recommend:

"Rebuild" your system. Back it up to Time Machine and then use Migration Assistant again, but only for your user folder (do not choose "Applications" and "Other Files & Folders") and maybe System & Network settings. Then reinstall all the software with Apple Silicon versions.

If you are sure that you ever only used homebrew to install packages, and not macport or direct pkg installers for python/go/etc,etc. Then you can use the following commands to clean out old homebrew and install it again from start. You might need to sudo rm a few stubborn folders after running these 2 commands (or if you are feeling brave, use sudo to run the uninstall.sh).
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh
/bin/bash uninstall.sh --path=/usr/local


